On R Identify when a qualitative variable changes from one value to another
On the x-axis I have dates and for each date I have a qualitative variable (colour). I would like to create on R a new df with the date on which my variable changes (e.g. the date from which I turn orange).



Date
Color




2003-08-21
Green


2003-09-01
Green


2003-09-11
Green


2003-09-21
Green


2003-10-01
Orange


2003-10-11
Orange


2003-10-21
Orange


2003-11-01
Black


2003-11-11
Black



I haven't found any solutions on the forum
Which I expect :



Date
Switch




2003-10-01
Green to orange


2003-11-01
Orange to black



I haven't tried anything because I haven't found anything that would allow me to do that
